# canvas shown on IE but not chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, canvas, grayscale

I want to use canvas to make an image to grayscale. There are a number of examples. But it has problem with my latest Chrome and Firefox. Surprisingly, IE9 is good. Is it the problem of my code?

And here is my code:

```
function draw() {
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
image = new Image();
image.src = 'ichiro.jpg';
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
imgd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 480, 400);
for (i=0; i<imgd.data.length; i+=4) {
    grays = imgd.data[i]*.3 + imgd.data[i+1]*.6 + imgd.data[i+2]*.1;
    imgd.data[i  ] = grays;   // red
    imgd.data[i+1] = grays;   // green
    imgd.data[i+2] = grays;   // blue
}
ctx.putImageData(imgd, 0, 0);

imggray = new Image();
imggray.src = canvas.toDataURL();
imggray.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(imggray, 0, 0);
}
```

}

I am new to HTML5 and javascript. So any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I misread your question. It is almost certainly because of a security error. You are not allowed to use `getImageData` if you have drawn an image to the canvas that is from a different "origin" (a different domain or from your local file system). In Chrome locally you can get around it if you do:

`C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files`

There's something called the origin-clean flag and it is removed once you drawImage from a different origin. All files are of a different origin for (good) security reasons.

---

Original answer:

You need to wait for image to load:

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/SYLW2/1107/

```
...
// this now happens only after the image is loaded:
image.onload = function() {
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
imgd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 480, 400);
for (i=0; i<imgd.data.length; i+=4) {
    grays = imgd.data[i]*.3 + imgd.data[i+1]*.6 + imgd.data[i+2]*.1;
    imgd.data[i  ] = grays;   // red
    imgd.data[i+1] = grays;   // green
    imgd.data[i+2] = grays;   // blue
}
ctx.putImageData(imgd, 0, 0);

imggray = new Image();
imggray.src = canvas.toDataURL();
imggray.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(imggray, 0, 0);
}
}
image.src = 'http://placekitten.com/400/400';
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread your question. It is almost certainly because of a security error. You are not allowed to use `getImageData` if you have drawn an image to the canvas that is from a different "origin" (a different domain or from your local file system). In Chrome locally you can get around it if you do: 


C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files

Comment: so where should I put the image so that getImageData() is allowed?

Comment: if you are hosting the page on a web server the image should be in the same directory. Open up the firefox developer console to see if you are still getting the security error (because its the only browser that bothers to tell you for some reason)

Comment: I can confirm that it is this problem. But what should I do if I want to test it in my own computer before sending to web server (other than turn off the security option)?

Comment: Unfortunately you either have to start chrome with that flag or you must run a tiny webserver from your machine (not too hard, google for small python web servers)